# Want to order by cast but after value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I'm using ajax to fetch more photos to a gallery based on views. The gallery already has a set of 10 photos showing. Now I want to get the next 10 photos in order based on view count from high to low.

```
    $last_image_view_count = 232;

    "SELECT * from `gallery` ORDER BY CAST(`views`<'$last_image_view_count' AS SIGNED) DESC LIMIT 10";
```

The code above works...but its not in order (230 - 216 - 205 etc). Its scattered but under 232. I need help figuring out how to get it in order from high to low.

Comment: The comparison returns either `0` or `1`. If you want to sort by the view count, why are you sorting by the comparison?

Comment: Shouldn't that comparison be in a WHERE clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"SELECT * from `gallery` WHERE `views` < '$last_image_view_count' ORDER BY `views`  DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Use the WHERE-statement to select only the desired set of data (from what I understand you want those, with a view-count that's less than `$last_image_view_count`).

You can then order it by the `views` column.

There's no need to cast it in the ORDER BY-statement. What you do with your code is ordering it by `1` or `0` (1 if views are less than your variable, otherwise 0).

Comment: This works, but it's putting it in order by the first number of a whole number... 402, 4, 398, 39, 38, 37, 365, 362, etc.